# How to create a list of variables in php?

Tags: php

I'm sorry for silly questiton but I can't understand, how to create a list of variables that will be used in if/else loop. I have a variable $category_id and different values of this variable (1,2,3, etc). I want to make a statment like this

```
if (isset($category_id) && $category_id == '1') {
some code here
}
```

but I need to specify more values of this variable like

```
if (isset($category_id) && $category_id == '1,2,5,11') {
some code here
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Put them in an array and use `in_array()`. PS: the `isset` call is suspicious there (and likely redundant).

Comment: Can you rephrase the problem? Do you want to know if your `$category_id` *list* contains all of the values in another *list*?

Comment: where do you get your `category_id` from, I think that's user input since he's checking if it's `isset` :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic even if it's a user's input - you barely need `isset`. It should never be the case when you don't know whether a variable is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the options you want to check for, then use `in_array` to check if one of them is used:

```
$categoryIds = array(1, 2, 5, 11);
if (isset($categoryId) && in_array($categoryId, $categoryIds)) {
    // some code here
}
```

This way when you add more IDs, only the array gets bigger rather than your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (isset($category_id) && (($category_id == '1')||($category_id == '2')||($category_id == '5')||($category_id == '11'))) {
some code here
}
```

Comment: what if the OP has like... 50? `in_array()` is by far a good start.

Comment: I wrote this assuming A Korolev is a beginner in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this method, but I have about 21 values.

Comment: Then Robbie's answer works best for you :)

Answer (score 0):

[switch()](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)

Example:

```
<?php
switch($category_id) {
    case 1:
        someCode();
        break;
    case 2:
        someCode();
        break;
    default:
        someCodeForIdsWhichAreNotOnAnyCase();
        break;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an `array` and a `loop` and a `switch / case` statement.

**e.g.**

```
$category_id = array('1','2','5','11');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($category_id); $i++) {

switch ($category_id[$i]) {
case ('1') : [CODE HERE]; break;
case ('2') : [CODE HERE]; break;
case ('5') : [CODE HERE]; break;
case ('11') : [CODE HERE]; break;
}

}
```